# Documentation for Droid Explorer?

Tags: droid-explorer

I can't find the simplest of information on anything for Droid Explorer. For instance, I did a backup, the backup screen disappeared, where does it put my *.ab file?

Does the Droid Explorer app have documentation?

Answer (score 3):

Documentation for Droid Explorer can be found on the [GitHub repository's wiki](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer/wiki).

Comment: As the lead developer of droid explorer, I want to point out that while this is a great answer to where the documentation is, the documentation is very limited. Also, the GitHub wiki and code is not official and won't be official until I do the next release.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I am the lead developer on Droid Explorer.*

As corti.nico said, those are the locations to find documentation. Documentation is very sparse. I am always looking for someone to help with creating documentation.

To answer where the backup file is saved, it is put in `%USERPROFILE%\Android Backups`. This is not currently configurable, but I have been working on making that configured as part of the install.